# Is it possible to play a video in repeat mode with Android DailyMotion SDK?

Tags: android, dailymotion-api

(Having it play again infinitely)

The sample app does not show any possibility to do that, but it is a common feature for video players. I tried to branch the end event to a seek-to-first-frame command but there is loading time between the 2 sequences.

Is there a tricky or standard way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

on `PlayerWebView` you can add a listener using

```
setEventListener(EventListener listener)
```

and listen for Event `PlayerWebView.EVENT_VIDEO_END`, on this event you can call

```
PlayerWebView.play()
```

Comment: Thank you, it is similar to the solution I tried but it is not really acceptable (not smooth).